# React Set State From CountDown Child

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have a `<CountDown/>` component that I'd like to hold it's own logic so it can be reusable else where in the app.

I'm struggling to reason how could I `setState` to `show:true` on a sibling component i.e `<List/>` once the count has reached 0.

Currently, this is the hierarchy of the components:

```js
export default class App extends Component {
  state = { show: false };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Countdown />
        <List {...this.state} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I'd like to show the contents of a `<List/>`

```
const fruits = ["banana", "apple", "peach"];
export const List = ({ show }) => fruits.map(fruit => <li className={show ? "show" : "hide"}>{fruit}</li>);
```

Once the `currentCount = 0`

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

export default class Countdown extends Component {
  state = { currentCount: 3 };

  // decrement timer method
  timer() {
    this.setState({
      currentCount: this.state.currentCount - 1
    });
    //clear interval
    if (this.state.currentCount < 1) {
      clearInterval(this.intervalId);
    }
  }

  // decrement every second i.e 1000
  componentDidMount() {
    this.intervalId = setInterval(this.timer.bind(this), 1000);
  }

  // Perform any necessary cleanup in this method, such as invalidating timers, canceling network requests, or cleaning up any subscriptions that were created in componentDidMount().
  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.intervalId);
  }
  render() {
    const { currentCount } = this.state;
    return <h1>{currentCount}</h1>;
  }
}
```

My struggle is that if I were to lift the state of `currentCount` to the main `<App/>` I'd lose the ability to control the `<CountDown/>` with its own state and lifecycle methods. Besides I'd like the CountDown to have its own set of logic so that It can be reusable and removable wherever I need in the app.

**Question:** How could I set the state of `show` (passed down as a prop) to true, once the countdown reaches 0?

Here's a [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/5klw988lqp)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define a method in App that will set the state `show` to true:

```
onFinish = () => {
   this.setState({ show: true });
};
```

Now send it as a props to CountDown:

```
<Countdown onFinish={this.onFinish} />
```

Now call it once your local state reached zero:

```
if (this.state.currentCount < 1) {
    clearInterval(this.intervalId);
    this.props.onFinish();
}
```

Here is [your Sandbox's fork](https://codesandbox.io/s/k75ly3mnr)

I also moved that last part of code on setState's callback because setState works in an asynchronous way.

Comment: Very elegant. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

You can create `showList()` in `<App>` and pass it to `<CountDown />` I have changed following part of code

```
timer() {
    this.setState({
      currentCount: this.state.currentCount - 1
    });
    //clear interval
    if (this.state.currentCount < 1) {
      clearInterval(this.intervalId);
      //This line is edited
      this.props.showList();
    }
  }
```

**App Component**

```
export default class App extends Component {
  state = { show: false };
  showList = () =>{
    this.setState({show:true});
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Countdown showList={this.showList}/>
        <List {...this.state} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/4w782mlz6w)**

Comment: Thank you, I accepted the other answer since they offer the same approach.